# How to make the response from server automatically shown on the textview (outlet3) when the register button is clicked

Tags: php, ios, swift

So now when the user input the id and password and hit the register button.
it will then submit to a php script that return a response.

The issue is right now i could get the response from php script only after i clicked on the textfield.

I am trying to make the response automatically shown on the textview (outlet3) when the register button is clicked.

```
 import UIKit

 var id00 = ""
 var pw00 = ""
 var result = ""
 var response = ""

 class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var outlet: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var outlet2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var outlet3: UITextField!

//register button

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    //get id &pw

    id00 = outlet.text!
    pw00 = outlet2.text!

    //imie

    let deviceUUID: String = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.152/testing00/user/reg.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "employeeid=" + id00 + "&password=" + pw00 + "&imie=" + deviceUUID ;

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

              self.outlet3.text = string

            print(self.outlet3.text!) //

        }
        print("response = \(request)") 
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you have been facing doing that ?

Comment: there isnt any error message. the problem is that the response text from php wont automatically  shown , it only show after i click in the text field, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this code:-

```
self.outlet3.text = string
```

With this code:-

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.outlet3.text = string
}
```